# flutter, failed to obtain access credentials

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-api, dialogflow-es

I'm using Dialogflow API for flutter application, yesterday, everything was working fine, today, this error kept appearing after every call of `detectIntent()`

I had made my device clock synchronized with NTP, but that didn't work

I'm actually kinda not understanding what is happening, so what should I do

error:

```
Failed to obtain access credentials. Error: invalid_grant Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp values in the JWT claim. Status code: 400
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone faced same problem, I just had to restart my machine after synchronization the clock with NTP :)